# Can't fix regex for decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying to figure out the regex for currency numbers (with max 2 decimal places).

I have tried this: `(0\.)?[1-9]+[\,\. ]*[0-9]{0,2}`.

It almost works, only it doesn't.


I'm trying to achieve the following:

- allow only numbers, a dot (.) and a comma (,)
- decimal numbers with either dot (.) or comma (,)

  both 3.14 and 1,61 should match
- limit numbers before dot or comma to 9

  123456789.12 should match
  123456789123.12 should NOT match
- decimals with max 2 decimal places

  3 should match
  3.1 should match
  3.14 should match
  3.1415 should NOT match
- allow single leading zero before dot or comma

  0.12 should match
  012 should NOT match

Comment: You almost certainly want `^` at the start and `$` at the end to ensure that extraneous characters are not ignored. Also, make use of online testers, e.g. https://www.regextester.com/

Comment: Hi PaxForce. I and many others feel with you. But you missed an intentional design decision of the the StackOverflow concept. See here https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote In short, StackOverflow wants votes (up and down) and needs to protect those who vote (down) from reataliation. That is why voting is anonymous - though commenting with explanation IS encouraged. (By the way, none of the downvotes is by me.)

Comment: Hey @Yunnosch - thank you for taking the time to explain this to me. I wish there were more people like you on stackoverflow and less of those who vent their frustration by down-voting without explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should work for you:

```
/^(?:[1-9]\d{0,8}|0)(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$/
```

If you want to search globally across some big text, try

```
/(?:^|[^\d,.])((?:[1-9]\d{0,8}|0)(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?)(?:[^\d,.]|$)/g
```

and use only the capture group to get the currency amount substring.

```js
const strings = [
  '3.14',
  '1,61',
  '123456789.12',
  '123456789123.12',
  '3',
  '3.1',
  '3.14',
  '3.1415',
  '0.12',
  '012'
];
const pattern = /^(?:[1-9]\d{0,8}|0)(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$/;
strings.forEach(str => {
  console.log(str+': '+(str.match(pattern)?'matched':'non matched'));
});
```